# How to use scriptlet inside javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

Can someone test this example and share the results?
http://timothypowell.net/blog/?p=23
When I do:

```
var myVar = '<% request.getContextPath(); %>';
alert(myVar);
```

I get : `'<% request.getContextPath(); %>'.`

Removing the enclosing single quotes from  '<% request.getContextPath(); %>';
 gives syntax error.
How can I use the scrptlet or expresion inside a js function?

EDIT: this link has an explanation that helped me:
http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=172082

Comment: Where did you put this code? If you're getting back JSP tags, it means the file isn't being processed by the server at all. Is it a `.jsp` file and is your server configured to handle them?

Comment: If it's JSP, ERB or similar, I guess you'd need a '=' for output:

`var myVar = '<%= request.getContextPath(); %>';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are placing the JSP code within a JavaScript page, or at least in a non-JSP page.  Scriptlets can only be included in a JSP page (typically configured to be *.jsp).

The statement as presented, if processed by the JSP compiler, would result in myVar being equal to '' as the scriptlet format you are using <% ... %> executes Java code between the tags, but does not return a result.

So, to use this tag you would need to manually write a value to the request output stream.  To get the desired functionality you need to do the following:

```
  make sure your code is in a JSP page
  use var myVar = '<%= request.getContextPath() %>'; (note the equals sign)
```

With all that said, scriptlets are viewed as bad practice in most cases.  For most cases, your should be using JSTL expressions and custom tags.

Comment: But what if I want to execute a function which does not return a result? Like session.inValidate() ?

Answer (score 5):

That line of code has to be placed in a HTML `<script>` tag in a `.jsp` file. This way the `JspServlet` will process the scriptlets (and other JSP/EL specific expressions).

```
<script>var myVar = '<%= request.getContextPath() %>';</script>
```

*Note that `<%= %>` is the right syntax to print a variable, the `<% %>` doesn't do that.*

Or if it is intended to be served in a standalone `.js` file, then you need to rename it to `.jsp` and add the following to top of the file (and change the `<script src>` URL accordingly):

```
<%@page contentType="text/javascript" %>
...
var myVar = '<%= request.getContextPath() %>';
```

This way the `JspServlet` will process it and the browser will be instructed to interpret the JSP response body as JavaScript instead of HTML.

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, note that *scriptlets* are considered [poor practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files). Use EL.

```
var myVar = '${pageContext.request.contextPath}';
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run `scriptlet` inside `javascript` by giving it normal `.js` extension. However you can give your `.js` the file extension of `.jsp` and then and link directly to it as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script.jsp"></script>
```

and now you can use `jsp` within your `javascript` like:

```
var someMessage = "${someMessage}"
var anotherMessage = "${anotherMessage}"/>"
```

This action is completely valid because what determines whether a file is a `javascript` file or not is what MIME media type. You can set MIME from JSP using:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/javascript" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myVar = '<%=request.getContextPath() %>';
alert(myVar);
```

You forgot to out put = before request and remove ; after getContextPath()