# using a scriplet inside a javascript function

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I wanted to use a scriplet inside a java script function. I wanted to check for some attribute's vale and give an alert according to that. Following is the function in which the only scriplet statement gives an error.

```
function UploadMessage() {
   <% if((String)request.getAttribute("SuccessMessage").compareTo("Uploaded successfully") == 0) { %>
        alert("File Successfully uploaded !");
    <% 
     } %>
}
```

Is there any way i can do this ? What is the problem here ?

**NOTE :** I have placed the above snippet in a jsp page

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use scriptlet inside javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158400/how-to-use-scriptlet-inside-javascript)

Comment: @mplungjan I have placed the scriplet in jsp page. Now is it a duplicate ?

Comment: The question I linked to is very similar to your question. In this case it was not the placing of the scriptlet but a syntax error you had an issue with. Still a good link for those who come after

Comment: In the future questions, please do not ignore/generalize errors as if they are useless garbage. They namely contain the answer. If you don't understand errors, post them in the question so that we can translate them in layman's terms. You know, once the error is *understood*, the solution is nothing more than obvious. So, do not say "I got errors", but copypaste them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function UploadMessage() {
       <% if(((String)request.getAttribute("SuccessMessage")).equals("Uploaded successfully")) { %>
            alert("File Successfully uploaded !");
        <% 
         } %>
    }
```

Problem was -

1. The method `compareTo(String)` is undefined for the type 
    Object
2. Incompatible operand types `String` and `int`

Comment: but the method compareTo(String) is undefined for the type Object yrr