# Javascript and scriptlet : can it be done?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, scriptlet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use scriptlet inside javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158400/how-to-use-scriptlet-inside-javascript)

```
<%
if(request.getAttribute("exception")!=null){%>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    alert("hi");

    parent.error.document.open();
    parent.error.document.write("bye");
    parent.error.document.write(<%=request.getAttribute("exception").toString()%>);
    parent.error.document.close();

</script>
</form>




<%}%>
```

Is it possible to have this sort of code? Is there any alternative?

Comment: It is possible if you use some [Tag Library](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tutorial/TagLibrariesTOC.html) instedd of scriptlets.

Comment: It is possible that you can define the java script in the scriplet condition.

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing some quotes to treat the value as a string, instead of a variable.

```
parent.error.document.write("<%=request.getAttribute("exception").toString()%>");
```

When printed to the page, it will appear as follows:

```
parent.error.document.write("myException");
```

Comment: even i am not getting the alert box displayed.

Comment: @abson then your `if` statement is failing... what you have is valid code, except for the quotes noted in the answer above.

Comment: it is going inside the if block but not printing or displaying the alert box

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. But I prefer JSTL:

```
<c:if test="${not empty(exception)}">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("hi");
        parent.error.document.open();
        parent.error.document.write("bye");
        parent.error.document.write(<%=request.getAttribute("exception").toString()%>);
        parent.error.document.close();

    </script>
</c:if>
```

Look more natural for jsp.