# Accessing getters inside my JavaScript tags

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have an `ArrayList<Product>` which I would like to access its getters inside my `<script>` tags. It just simply does not work. I am wondering if is there a possibility that I can access the values of the getters inside my `<script>` tags.

JavaScript:

```
var counter = 1;
var iteration1 = "productid" + counter;
var iteration2 = "orderquantity" + counter;
var totalPrice = 0;
function compute() {
    while(document.getElementById(iteration1)[0] !== null && document.getElementById(iteration2)[0] !== null) {
        var price = 0;
        var isDone = false;
        for(var i = 0; i < products.size() && isDone === false; i++) {
            if(products.get(i).getProductID() === document.getElementById(iteration1)[0]) {
                price = products.get(i).getProductPrice() * document.getElementById(iteration2)[0];
                totalPrice += price;
                isDone = true;
            }
        }
        counter++;
        iteration1 = "productid" + counter;
        iteration2 = "orderquantity" + counter;
    }
    document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = totalPrice;
}
```

I was also thinking if I can access its values using other solutions like placing its values inside a `<a id="iteration1">` or something. But I cannot seem to find a solution since the variables inside my Java is different from the values inside my `id=""`.

```
<%
    ArrayList<Product> products = (ArrayList<Product>)session.getAttribute("filteredproducts");
    int counter = 1;
    String iteration1 = "productid" + counter;
    String iteration2 = "orderquantity" + counter;
    for(Product p: products) {
%>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a id="iteration1"><%=p.getProductID()%></a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%=p.getProductLine()%> (Php <a id="iteration2"><%=p.getProductPrice()%></a>)
    </td>
</tr>
<%}%>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158400/how-to-use-scriptlet-inside-javascript

Comment: Thanks, @A5l-lE5! I finally got it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally solved my problem with the help of the link above in the comment section. Just to share it, here is the code I used:

JavaScript:

```
function compute() {
    var counter = 1;
    var iteration1 = "productid" + counter;
    var iteration2 = "productquantity" + counter;
    var totalPrice = 0;
    var idArray = new Array();
    var priceArray = new Array();
    <%
        for(Product p: products) {
    %>
        idArray.push("<%=p.getProductID()%>");
        priceArray.push("<%=p.getProductPrice()%>");
    <%}%>
    for(var j = 0; j < click; j++) {
        var isDone = false;
        for(var i = 0; i < idArray.length && isDone === false; i++) {
            if(idArray[i] === document.getElementById(iteration1).value) {
                totalPrice += priceArray[i] * document.getElementById(iteration2).value;
                isDone = true;
            }
        }
        counter++;
        iteration1 = "productid" + counter;
        iteration2 = "productquantity" + counter;
    }
    document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = totalPrice;
}
```